# Apache Rewrite Rule: If Not Subfolder A and Not Subfolder B do something

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My websites had english as default language and german as addition language.
The default link was `example.org` and the german part was in `example.org/de`

Now I have changed my default language to german.
The german part is still in `example.org/de` but the english part moved to `example.org/en`

I want to redirect every URL which is not in subfolder /de or /en to my english subfolder. It should be like `if (!example.org/en && !example.org/de) { do something }`

Some examples:

```
example.org/mysite --> example.org/en/mysite
example.org/differentsubfolder/index --> example.org/en/differentsubfolder.index
example.org/de/index --> no changes
example.org/en/index --> no changes
```

What I tried is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.org/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This seems to work on most of the pages but pages are loading extremly slow, so I think I made something wrong.

Does somebody no what is wrong with it?

Comment: Slowness is not caused by .htaccess usually. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302/404 URLs you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule !^(en|de)(.*)/?$ en/$1 [NC,L]
```